# Inherited constructor choice based on condition

Tags: c#

I have a set of inherited classes. Depending on initialization variable type I need to call corresponding constructor.
I want to avoid using switch branches here, just in case weapon types will get more and more types. Maybe there is generic approach or some pattern to achieve this?
Weapon init:

```
switch (_weaponsData.WeaponType) 
{
    case WeaponType.ProjectileWeapon:
    weapon = new ProjectileWeapon(_weaponsData);
    break;

    case WeaponType.Laser:
    weapon = new LaserWeapon(_weaponsData);
    break;

    case WeaponType.snowBall:
    weapon = new SnowballWeapon(_weaponsData);
    break;
}
```

Custom weapon's constructors:

```
public class ProjectileWeapon : BasicWeapon
{
    public ProjectileWeapon(WeaponData weaponData) : base(weaponData) { }
}

public class LaserWeapon : BasicWeapon
{
    public LaserWeapon(WeaponData weaponData) : base(weaponData) { }
}

public class SnowballWeapon : BasicWeapon
{
    public SnowballWeapon(WeaponData weaponData) : base(weaponData) { }
}
```

Comment: If you store the `Type` of the classes in your _weaponsData you can instantiate them with `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: The code you've written is essentially the [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 6):

This sort of thing is kind of unavoidable, but if you really want to avoid the `case switch` structure you can use a dictionary of delegates, where the key is the type and the value is a `Func<BasicWeapon>`.

```
var map = new Dictionary<WeaponType,Func<WeaponData,BasicWeapon>>
{
    { WeaponType.ProjectileWeapon, d => new ProjectileWeapon(d) },
    { WeaponType.LaserWeapon,      d => new LaserWeapon(d) },
    { WeaponType.SnowballWeapon,   d => new SnowballWeapon(d) },
};
```

Then to create a new weapon object, just call

```
weapon = map[_weaponsData.WeaponType](_weaponsData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define static method in base class to handle creation of new instances:

```
public class BasicWeapon
{
    public static BasicWeapon CreateNew(WeaponData _weaponsData)
    {
        // As @Gusman said in comments, if you store Type of classes in 
        // _weaponsData, then you can use :
        // return Activator.CreateInstance(_weaponsData.Type, _weaponsData);
        // Or:
        switch (_weaponsData.WeaponType)
        {
            case WeaponType.ProjectileWeapon:
                return new ProjectileWeapon(_weaponsData);
            case WeaponType.Laser:
                return new LaserWeapon(_weaponsData);
            case WeaponType.snowBall:
                return new SnowballWeapon(_weaponsData);
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and wherever you want, you can use:

```
var weapon = BasicWeapon.CreateNew(_weaponsData);
```